# R read.csv with ISO-8859-13 encoding

Tags: r, read.csv

I have a big issue in reading in .csv files into R that are in Eastern Europe ISO-8859-13 encoding. Does anybody have solution for this?

```
read.csv("myFile.csv", encoding = "ISO-8859-13")
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to read csv data with unknown encoding in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16681812/how-to-read-csv-data-with-unknown-encoding-in-r)

Comment: What is going wrong? For instance, what happens when you use `read.csv` with argument `fileEncoding = "ISO-8859-13"`?

Comment: Try `data.table::fread()`

Comment: @Scarabee Thanks! 

I was trying `encoding="ISO-8859-13` instead of  `fileEncoding='ISO-8859-13"`.

Answer (score 4):

We need to use *fileEncoding* instead of *encoding* (as suggeseted by @Scarabee in the comments):

```
read.csv("myFile.csv", fileEncoding = "ISO-8859-13")
```

---

In bash we can retrieve the file encoding with:

```
$ file -i ./weirdo.csv
```

Tell R how the file is encoded by pasting the output from `charset=` which could be for example `charset=iso-8859-1`

```
read.csv("weirdo.csv", fileEncoding = "iso-8859-1")
```